# Ghost error with M2 Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, nexus

I deleted the .m2 directory.
I make the m2 eclipse use a settings.xml which points to a nexus server.

I use Eclipse Juno and downloaded the M2 plugin.
Go to the maven settings and click "download source"s and "javadoc".
Click ok and close the dialog.

Go the file menu and create a new maven project with artefact java6se-spring3-archetype (not relevant).
Voilà, new project is created.

I open the eclipse "Error log" : "could not download sources for..." a bunch of jars, for instance : log4j:1.2.14.
Ok, I open the MavenDependencies line on the left, and go the log4j, click any class in it : the source code appears.

My question : Why does m2 say it cannot download the sources when in fact, it has ?

Thank you for your help,

Regards,

Comment: Continued my research. In fact for some classes, it has not downloaded the sources. for ex, I get Could not download sources for org.springframework:spring-asm:3.1.0.RELEASE and it is correct : no sources. I also get "Could not download sources for org.springframework:spring-expression:3.1.0.RELEASE" : This is wrong : the sources ARE present....

Answer (score 0):

After much research and googling : 
https://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/issues/detail?id=30

The sources are incorrectly attached to the jar.
Maven still says some lies for other jars which are incorrectly reported as not having their sourcse available.
I close the question though, got better things to do :)